# Configure SPDY on tomcat 8 windows

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8, spdy

I'm developing a web application with eclipse and tomcat 8 in windows, now i want to setup SPDY. I must use apache tomcat 8, this is a constraint project. 
How can I configure my web application to use SPDY in tomcat 8?

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: i wrote a mail to apache users mailing list and they gave me this reply:

SPDY support was experimental and for a much older version of SPDY than
any current browser supports. Tomcat's SPDY support is not usable in its
current form.

HTTP/2 support will be available in Tomcat 9.